# Room Dao can't access table name in Android project

Tags: android

My Dao

```
        @Dao
        public interface DrugDao {
            @Query("SELECT * FROM drugs")
            List<Drug> getDrugList();
            @Insert
            void insertDrug(Drug drug);
            @Update
            void updateDrug(Drug drug);
            @Delete
            void deleteDrug(Drug drug);
        }
```

My Entity

```
        @Entity(tableName = "drugs")
        public class Drug {
            @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
            private int id;
            @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
            private String name;
            @ColumnInfo(name = "dose")
            private int dose;
            @ColumnInfo(name = "frequency")
            private String frequency;
            @ColumnInfo(name = "checkBoxId")
            private String checkBoxId;
            @ColumnInfo(name = "checkBoxStatus")
            private boolean checked;
```

Database class

```
    @Database(entities = Drug.class, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
    public abstract class DrugDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        private static final String DB_NAME= "drug_db";
        private static DrugDatabase instance;
    
        public static synchronized DrugDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DrugDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    
        public abstract DrugDao drugDao();
    }
```

I have two classes here, one is a Dao and one is an object. The goal is to store the objects in the database. For some reason the Dao @Query cannot access the table name as defined in the object. I get the error on the "drugs" as being Cannot resolve symbol 'drugs'.

Comment: Have you added drugs entity to database implementation ?

Comment: My formatting may be bad but I pasted in the database class into the question. I think i have.

Comment: Have you created getters, setters in the Drug entity for its fields ?

Comment: yes, I didn't include them here because I thought they weren't necessary. My IDE's only error/red mark right now is the table name in the Dao.

Comment: Please post the proper error log here